# 400 using Axios to make a post request to Django Rest Framework

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm working with learning some javascript to make a post to a little rest API I created with django rest. I have a post that works when I was working with jQuery but now I am reimplementing using Vue.js and am hitting a snag. When I do the below post request I get a 400 error and am not sure what I am missing. I would imagine something with my header is incorrect? Any advice would be welcome.

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/matches/',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
```

jQuery post for reference:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/matches/",
    data: JSON.stringify(final_data),
    success: function() {},
    error: function(err) {console.log(err)},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain:false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
});
```

Comment: any way you can log the body of your 400 response from Django REST framework? Usually the reason for the 400 error is in the response body.

Comment: @DavidM. even when I log for the error nothing comes back. it is like it isn't even getting to my endpoint

Comment: I'm not familiar with Axios but quickly scanning through the Github docs https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios leads me to believe you should be using Axios as a Promise (`axios.post(...).then(...)`)?

Comment: @DavidM. even like this I still do not get anything logging to the console https://gist.github.com/anonymous/677d2c4832d140762cbfc3574857bcc8

Comment: And your browser's development tools do not display anything in Network tab?

Comment: Seconding David here, we need the content of the response.